# Multiplayer game how to use multitouch 

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, multi-touch, game-physics

I'm making a game where 2 people have either side of an iphone screen to move their piece. I'm having some trouble with the multitouch part, multiple touch is set to on as well. This is the current code, I need both users to be able to move at the same time, currently only one can.

Yellow and green are the two pieces being moved(only on the x axis)

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
location = [touch locationInView:self.view];  
if (location.y > 230) { 
    locationYellow = location; 
    yellow.center = CGPointMake(locationYellow.x, yellow.center.y); 
}else{
    locationGreen = location;   
    if (VSModeON == YES) {
        green.center = CGPointMake(locationGreen.x, green.center.y);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually said what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, the problem is that it doesn't work. Only one paddle can be moving at a time

Comment: @Jordan Brown: "the problem is that it doesn't work" is unclear beyond unclear. It's best to avoid saying things like that and *just explain how* it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
```

This takes, as it sounds like it would, any object from the touches. This code is typically used where you are only expecting single touches. Your current code will only deal with one touch at a time.

For multi touch you need to analyse each touch in the set `[event touchesForView:self.view]` and act accordingly.

So something like

```
for (UITouch *aTouch in [event touchesForView:self.view])
{
    // Deal with each touch here...
}
```